# How to group , totalize and pivot wider by date?

Tags: r

I have a skinny dataset

```
df = structure(list(id= c("20210301168026390916", "20210301168026390916", 
"20210301168026390916"), date= c("2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", 
"2021-06-22"), usd= c(34403, 3333, 22256), provider= c("900098550", 
"900098550", "901098333")), .Names = c("id", "date", 
"usd", "provider"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can you please advise a way to group records by provider and date and totalize the usd values so the resulting table will be:

```
Provider     2021_05    2021_06
900098550    34403        3333
901098333    0           22256
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `format` the `Date` converted 'date' to include only the year-month, then with `pivot_wider` reshape from 'long' to 'wide' while specifying the `values_fn` as `sum` and `values_fill` as 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   select(-id) %>%
   mutate(date = format(as.Date(date), '%Y-%m')) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = usd, 
         values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  provider  `2021-05` `2021-06`
#  <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 900098550     34403      3333
#2 901098333         0     22256
```

---

Or can use `dcast` from `data.table` (Note that `dcast` with `reshape2` is also of the same syntax )

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), provider ~ format(as.Date(date), '%Y-%m'), 
      value.var = 'usd', fill = 0, fun.aggregate = sum)
```

-output

```
#     provider 2021-05 2021-06
#1: 900098550   34403    3333
#2: 901098333       0   22256
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `tapply`

```
with(df, tapply(usd, list(provider, date = format(as.Date(date), 
       '%Y-%m')), FUN = sum))
```

---

In addition to the above options, there is `pivottabler`, which also creates additional margins

```
library(pivottabler)
df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date), '%Y-%m')   
qpvt(df, "provider", "date", "sum(usd)")
#           2021-05  2021-06  Total  
#900098550    34403     3333  37736  
#901098333             22256  22256  
#Total        34403    25589  59992
```

Comment: The reason why I left out reshape its because it will not aggregate/sum the values. You will have to use transform+aggregate+reshape  yet I could only use transform+xtabs

Answer (score 3):

In base R you will do:

```
xtabs(usd~provider+date, transform(df, date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m")))
           date
provider    2021-05 2021-06
  900098550   34403    3333
  901098333       0   22256
```

For the base R option. If you need a dataframe back, you could do:

```
 a <-  xtabs(usd~provider+date, transform(df, date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m")))
cbind(provider = rownames(a), as.data.frame.matrix(a, 1))
   provider 2021-05 2021-06
1 900098550   34403    3333
2 901098333       0   22256
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  transform(df, date = format(as.Date(date), "%Y_%m")),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "provider",
  timevar = "date",
  drop = "id"
)
```

gives

```
   provider usd.2021_05 usd.2021_06
1 900098550       34403        3333
3 901098333          NA       22256
```